# VirtualBox Ubuntu Guest Addition Problem ( Mouse and Screen )

Tags: virtualbox

So, I have Ubuntu in Virtuell box and I wanted to have a chared clipboard and be able to go into fullscreen mode, so I installed Guest additions.

Now I have the problem, that my window is always the same size and the rest of the screen is grey ( see Pic) and I also cant click within the area that is not grey. The keystrokes at the side work fine and when I go into the menu I can click everywhere as long as it's not in the area that was not gray in the normal view.

Pls help me, I feel like I've searched the whole internet now, seems like no one else has this problem.  [Ubuntu Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23L11.png).

Answer (score 0):

Your Guest Additions are not properly installed. You could see it in a terminal output while installing.

Run

```
sudo apt install dkms
```

Then reinstall Guest Additions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case of running Ubuntu22.04 from Windows10 I fixed this problem by changing the graphic controller in settings to VBoxVGA.

Hope it helps